# What options can be put into a SSH authorized_keys file?

Tags: ssh

I found [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20101218001225/http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html) on options that can be put before a key in the authorized_keys file. I was wondering though, are there more? Options listed in the article are

- from="domain"
- command="commandtorun"
- no-port-forwarding
- no-X11-forwarding
- no-agent-forwarding
- no-pty

*Update*
It appears that the original article is now inaccessible. Because of that I've now changed the link to point to the archive.org version.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: ah, good find @starfry. I've updated the link to point to the archive.org  snapshot.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

All options are detailed in the [sshd(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) man page; search for **AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT**.

At the moment, those options are:

- `cert-authority`
- `command="command"`
- `environment="NAME=value"`
- `expiry-time="timespec"`
- `from="pattern-list"`
- `no-agent-forwarding`
- `no-port-forwarding`
- `no-pty`
- `no-user-rc`
- `no-X11-forwarding`
- `permitlisten="[host]:port"`
- `permitopen="host:port"`
- `principals="principals"`
- `restrict`
- `tunnel="n"`

Comment: ah... that's the man page I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check 'man sshd' on your local unix-ish box for more info.  My osx box has the following:

- command="command"
- environment="NAME=value"
- from="pattern-list"
- no-agent-forwarding
- no-port-forwarding
- no-pty
- no-user-rc
- no-X11-forwarding
- permitopen="host:port"
- tunnel="n"