# Using command in ssh authorized_keys breaks scp

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, scp

I would like to use command per key in **authorized_keys** to set some environment variables.

```
command="MYVAR=test $SHELL" ssh-rsa mykey
```

Shell works fine but scp is not working.

What would be the correct way to set environment variables per key and not break ssh file transfers?

Comment: Have you considered setting your variables in `~/.ssh/rc`?  Or how about `environment="NAME=value"`.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/142997/what-options-can-be-put-into-a-ssh-authorized-keys-file

Comment: Thanks, Zoredache. environment param solves my problem. You can add your solution as an answer to this question, I would accept it for you to get reputation points.

Answer (score 4):

Your configuration forces ssh to run whatever command is in `$SHELL` whenever you connect with the matching private key.  This is fine if what you want is an interactive shell, but will break any attempt at running a command directly.  This breaks `scp as you've seen, but will also break things like:

```
ssh myhost uptime
```

The solution is to either (a) set your environment variables somewhere else (`.ssh/rc`, or just use your standard shell initialization files), or (b) use a dedicated key when you want to force a command via your `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem was that I want to set environment variables per ssh key. It was solved by Zoredache suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

So I realize this question is ancient at this point but I discovered an answer to this today. This is an alternative to setting environment variables and may be a better solution depending on your situation. My situation is this:

I have a Splunk instance that initiates an SCP and SSH session to a remote host. A list of emails is sent via SCP and then SSH is used to run a script on the remote system to take action on that list of emails. Here's the top of my authorized_keys file:

```
command="/home/username/wrapper.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3 etc...
```

This is my wrapper.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

vars=( $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND )
case "${vars[0]}" in
        "/home/username/scripts/myscript.py")
                /home/username/scripts/myscript.py ${vars[1]}
                exit 0
                ;;
        "scp")
                scp -t ${vars[2]}
                chmod 644 ${vars[2]}
                exit 0
                ;;
        *)
                exit 1
                ;;
esac
```

The first case allows /home/username/scripts/myscript.py with any command line parameters that were passed to it.
The second, scp case entry, allows the incoming file to be written to disk at its intended location.

This method allows me to limit the use of the public key to 1 command and still allow scp. If anyone has a better option please share. :)